# Loop through a named range

Tags: excel, vba

I have worksheet containing a load of cells formatted as currency made into a range using vba. I would like to loop through all the cells in the range and change the currency format the code I am trying is belowcode below:

```
Dim c As Range
Dim rnge As Range
Dim c as Range

Set rnge = Range("CampusCurrRng")
For Each c In rnge
    If Left(cell, 1) = "£" And cell.Value <> "" Then
        Left(cell, 1) = "R" And cell.Value * 50
    End If
Next
```

I keep getting the error 1004 Method 'Range' of object'_worksheet' failed. Has anyone any ideas why? and how to solve it.

Thank you

Comment: What line do you get the error on? You don't define `cell` - should it be `c`?

Comment: In the "For Each c" loop, shouldn't you have "c" instead of "cell", like for instance "If Left(c, 1) = "

Comment: What currency is `R`? South African Rand?

Comment: Is the code in a worksheet module? It would be simpler to use a Style in my opinion. Then all you need to do is edit the style's number format, not loop through all the cells.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `NumberFormat` of the Cells, `Left` will not work here.
See code below

```
Dim rnge As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rnge = Range("CampusCurrRng")
For Each cell In rnge
    ' in case you use pound in whatever format
    If InStr(cell.NumberFormat, "£") > 0 And cell.Value <> "" Then
        ' used the Rand default of Excel, can modify this line according to your need
        cell.NumberFormat = "[$R-430]#,##0.00"
        cell.Value = cell.Value * 50
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `InStr(cell.NumberFormat, "£")` will return 0 so code won't work (just tested it). See my code below - `NumberFormatLocal` solves this problem. Also you declare `c` but never use it.

Comment: the `c` part was just copied from PO, worked very nicely with the several tests I've done

Answer (score 0):

If your values are currency formatted then using `left` will not work - it pulls back the first digit, not the currency prefix.

This code may help you get started. It converts `£` to `R` (South African Rand).

```
Sub CurrencyConverter()
    Dim cl As Range, rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("CampusCurrRng")

    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.NumberFormatLocal = "£#,##0;[Red]-£#,##0" And cl.Value <> "" Then
            cl = cl * 50
            cl.NumberFormat = "[$R-1C09] #,##0;[Red][$R-1C09] -#,##0"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Notes:**

To check for `£` you need to specify the currency format. This is tricky. For example, I am in the UK and if I have £100 in cell A1:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat ~~~> $#,##0_);[Red]($#,##0)
Range("A1").NumberFormatLocal ~~~> £#,##0;[Red]-£#,##0
```

You need to use `NumberFormatLocal` to pick up `£`. Put another way, this code will produce a negative result in the loop:

```
If cl.NumberFormat = "£#,##0;[Red]-£#,##0"...
```

The next bit is easier. You need to specify the output currency format. For South African Rand I have:

```
cl.NumberFormat = "[$R-1C09] #,##0;[Red][$R-1C09] -#,##0"
```

To get the one you need I would do the following:

1. Type a random value in a random cell e.g. 100 in cell A1
2. Select the cell and press `F1` (brings up the Format Cells dialog)
3. Select `Currency` in the left hand navigation
4. Select your desired currency format in the `Symbol` drop down menu
5. Click `OK`
6. Now press `F1` again
7. In the left hand navigation select `Custom`
8. The right hand navigation will now show the correct format

This all seems a little like hard work. I am interested to see if any simpler approaches surface!

Comment: Tried this. I still get the error 1004, Does it mean anything if the watch window tells me that rng is out of context?

Comment: on the " Set rng = Range("CampusCurrRng")" line

Comment: You would get that error if you haven't got a defined range called `CampusCurrRng`. Possible spelling error?

Answer (score 0):

shorter version that will keep your number format

```
For Each c In [CampusCurrRng] 
    If c.Text Like "*£*" Then c.Value = c * 50: _
        c.NumberFormat = Replace(c.NumberFormat, "£", "R")
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested this but try `Dim c as variant`. Alternatively, you can omit it completely if option has not been set to explicit since any variable that has not been declared is automatically dim_ed as variant type.

Also, unless your named range is of workbook scope, I would like to suggest that you add its worksheet specification to ensure everything runs predictably.

e.g.

```
Set rnge = Worksheets("example").Range("CampusCurrRng")
```

Lastly, like what M Lind said, it should be c instead of cell (missed that out on the first pass).